# What is a way to detect the owner of a global keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

There are a bunch of keyboard shortcuts I've used globally in Windows (assigned via Directory Opus) over the years and every now and then some new program or driver I install steals their focus away from DOpus.
Then I spend time figuring out who's the culprit by killing processes via Process Explorer until the keys come back to DOpus.

Is there a more elegant way of discovering which windows process is the current owner of a certain keyboard shortcut?

Comment: You can read [Find out what process registered a global hotkey? (Windows API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api) This should be a similar question as yours and there are some useful answers might help you.